# C++ '>' bitwise operator

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Anyone know > does in C++ in terms of bitwise operators? Here's an example of it being used:

```
    void Seed(uint64_t seed){
        Seed(seed>32, seed);
    };

    void Seed(uint32_t high, uint32_t low){
        if((high != low) && low && high){
            DRandomSeedHigh = high;
            DRandomSeedLow = low;   
        }
    };
```

Comment: Looks like it's a typo and it's supposed to be `>>`.

Comment: So that's the code running in production? Then it's got to be a bug.

Comment: `>` is a logical operator, not a bitwise one. This is most definitely supposed to be `>>`.

Comment: Yep you guys are right. I was confused because the code wasn't written by me but I confirmed with the offer it should be  >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the comments say,  this is a typo and should be `>>`.

But your question was about what this does.   `>` is not a bitwise operator,  but `>>` is.   It splits an unsigned 64 bit value in two.  The bit shift operator is used to get the top 32 bits,  while the low 32 bits are passed as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 1):

`>` returns an integer, with value 1 if true and 0 if false.